# How do I delete my entire Stack Exchange account?

Tags: discussion, deleted-accounts

Stack Exchange seems to have made it impossible to delete accounts. I can delete the accounts from other individual sites like Ask Ubuntu, but I can't delete the main account on stackexchange.com. *I want to be rid of Stack Exchange completely!* I don't want a Stack Exchange account whatsoever! I really don't like Stack Exchange and I want nothing to do with it. Please help me delete my stackexchange.com account!

Comment: @PolyGeo He doesn't ask for the deletion of a specific account, he wants to delete his network-wide account.

Comment: @peterh "If you want to be removed from all sites, you must fill out the contact form and complete the process on all sites."

Comment: 1. ask the SE, either they will do or won't 2. If they don't, then rename your main SE login to an unremarkable one 3. delete all of your site accounts 4. revoke the permission of the SE to access your data in your google security settings.

Comment: @Polygeo Also this doesn't answer the question. He wants more, as to delete all of his accounts. He also wants to delete his cross-site data (what you can see on http://stackexchange.com).

Comment: @peterh "Content you've posted on the site is owned by you but licensed to Stack Exchange, and you therefore cannot request that it be deleted with your account."

Comment: @Polygeo Another misunderstand: he didn't said he would want to delete also his content. He wants to delete his network-wide account. The normal SE behavior about the content of the deleted accounts (they still remain, but their poster is greyed out) is probably enough for him. I think you don't know enough details, how the SE accs are working. I reaply: the networkwide acc is what you can see on the http://stackexchange.com, it contains your google datas and auth key, usw.

Comment: Pretty soon, the SE.com profile won't "exist" in the sense of having an account anymore, and it will always disappear once all other site profiles are deleted (which already happens in most cases now). Currently, it's possible to have it not disappear if you explicitly created an account by logging in on that site (the vast majority of our users don't), but that weird side-affect thing will go away soon.

Comment: I opt for (and will flag for) removing the 'duplicate' status of this question. As explained by @peterh-ReinstateMonica this is a different question with a different answer. Any EU user has the right to be forgotten (so personal data like email, name and password). The linked question and accepted answer do not cover this. Marking this a duplicate only adds to the confusion. In response to animuson data being hidden after some time period is not enough to cover the right to be forgotten.

Comment: Isn't this against European regulations? What about GDPR? You StackExchange deserve to be sued for this...

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to contact Stack Exchange directly to request that.  On a site where you still have an account, click the "contact us" link at the bottom, choose "other" for the reason, and explain that you'd like to delete your network account in addition to your accounts on individual sites.  I don't know if they'll do that for you, but there's no way for you or for site moderators to do it, so asking them is your only option.

(If you reset your user name to the default "user#####" and delete your accounts on all sites, that'll be as good as gone.  You won't get any notifications since those come from specific sites, so if you log out and walk away, SE will be dead to you.)

Comment: They'll do it if requested, after all it's easier than handling separate requests for every site. (Source: own experience.)

Comment: To bad he didn't accept this answer before he was successful. Something worked, cause the user name is no longer a link.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Users can instantly self-delete if they haven't voted and haven't posted more than once. Doesn't require our intervention or any sort of wait.

Comment: I actually used the above suggested "contact us" approach for an old account I had and I am deeply impressed by how it was handled. All GDPR rights covered and very quick support. Job well done SE !

Comment: If you're in the EU you're covered by General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), although it seems to me that companies don't really GAS.

Comment: @user222834 In my own experience working for other employees (one of them was big enough to have offices thoughout the whole Spain country)... no company gives a shit about GDPR... they just pretend they do. And so seems to be the case with StackExchange. If I was rich, I would sue them right away for this.

Comment: @pjvleeuwen Good to know it worked for you (yet I imagine it would be like Microsoft phone service for some reason: a pain!). Why don't pjt a damn "Master Button" for this? Why is it so hard for US Europeans to get our GDPR rights granted (even for deleting!!) while Big Techs keep violating the law over and over? THIS IS WAR!!!!!