# How do I delete my main Stack Exchange account?

Tags: bug, user-interface, user-accounts, email, deleted-accounts

I've deleted all my sub Stack Exchange sites, like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour). I do not have any profile now.

I wish to delete my main account as well. But there is no such option to remove it. I want to completely remove any account associated with my email, but the main account itself doesn’t seem to allow to be deleted ever if everything else was deleted.

I need help!

**Note**: I had to create a *meta* account for this.

Comment: See especially [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291576/how-do-i-delete-my-entire-stack-exchange-account#comment946743_291576) - I'd blame caching.